# laravel 6 user id return null

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 6 I want to get logIn user's id when I use `Auth::user()` it return me all of the  user's information but when I use this code it returns me null

```
$user = Auth::user();
die($user->id);
```

- I've used some questions but they've not given me any answer

This is my HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        die(Auth::id());

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

However if I `use Auth::user()->name` it returns me name of user

Comment: Does your `users` table have an `id` column? Also, how about `Auth::user()->id`? Can you post a `dd(Auth::user())` into your question?

Comment: Yes , I have id column

Comment: What about the rest of my comment? Does `Auth::user()->id` work? Can you post a `dd(Auth::user());` please.

Comment: Try to use `\Auth::id()` instead work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dd($user->id)` instead, you currently have `Auth::id()`, also make sure you're only trying to access the `$user->id` after you logged in to your application, if you have not logged in, it will return *null*.

Comment: My ```di()``` method does not return the id but ```dd()``` is returning , Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` is full `array` of user data , you can select `id` from it to return the id , as you are returning the `Auth::user()->name.`

```
Auth::user()->id
```